# JavaScript SDK for Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to get the access token for facebook and I got this code from facebook developer website but it can't generate or give me any access token . I use this code in a simple text file not any of my website.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
<div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="true" data-width="400" data-max-rows="1"></div>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '377263832388887', // App ID
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
        // app, and response.authResponse supplies
        // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
        // request, and the time the access token 
        // and signed request each expire
        var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
        var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

        // TODO: Handle the access token

    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
        // but has not authenticated your app
    } else {
        // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
    }
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
});
</script>
```

I want to get access token so that I can further proceed for my work. Thank you.

Comment: Are you actually asking the user to authorize your app? Without it you will not get an access token.

Answer (score 0):

consider using this code provided by http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

replace the FB.Event.subscribe function with the following.

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

    // dump success data here, and dump response data if needed

  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {

    // dump fail data here

  } else {
    // dump other fail data here
  }
  });
```

Although I see on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/ that the FB.Event.subscribe should also have the access code in its result array.  Have you tried dumping the 'response' to console, to view the results?

Comment: I want to build application or want to crawl my own status through c# for this I need access token , and for access token I need to code in javaScript SDK which I have no idea

Comment: This function is a part of the Javascript SDK as well.  have you tried to dump the 'response' to see what you are getting back?  I can not help you with C# sorry.  Perhaps if you add a C# tag to your question someone else may help you.  It seems likely that you may be able to authenticate server-side.

Comment: I just need access code which only deal with JavaScript SDK and when I execute this code web browser return nothing

Comment: ok I edited the answer to better reflect the idea.  you will use the same code you provided in the original question, but replace FB.Event.subscribe function.  Also where the comments are in the new function is where I recommend you dump your results so you can see better where the problem is, if there is one.